# How to fix the datetime2 out-of-range conversion error using DbContext and SetInitializer?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I'm using the DbContext and Code First APIs introduced with Entity Framework 4.1.

The **data model** uses basic data types such as `string` and `DateTime`. The only data annotation I'm using in some cases is `[Required]`, but that's not on any of the `DateTime` properties. Example:

```
public virtual DateTime Start { get; set; }
```

The **DbContext subclass** is also simple and looks like:

```
public class EventsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().ToTable("Events");
    }
}
```

The **initializer** sets dates in the model to sensible values in either this year or next year.

However when I run the initializer, I get this error at `context.SaveChanges()`:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value. The
>   statement has been terminated.

I don't understand why this is happening at all because everything is so simple. I'm also not sure how to fix it since there is no edmx file to edit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler to see insert / update SQL statements? It is quite hard to say what is going on here - we don't see your initializer or entities. SQL Profiler will help you a lot to localize issue.

Comment: In my case I had added a field to a table and edit form, forgot to update the Bind Includes and my field was getting set to NULL. So the error helped correct my oversight.

Comment: Related post - [Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type results out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1331779/465053)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You have to ensure that Start is greater than or equal to SqlDateTime.MinValue (January 1, 1753) - by default Start equals DateTime.MinValue (January 1, 0001).

Comment: I had left some of my initializer objects without a set date, so it would have been defaulting to DateTime.MinValue.

Comment: I did that too ^.  Added a custom date field to the asp.net identity ApplicationUser object then forgot to initialize it to something that made sense.  : (

Comment: In my case, the problem was in the min date, 01/01/0001 was generating the error.

Comment: how i can check dateTime.minvalue ?

Comment: A little late, but @Anabeil you should be able to just Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MinValue) in the immediate window of VS/linqpad

Answer (score 24):

In some cases, `DateTime.MinValue` (or equivalenly, `default(DateTime)`) is used to indicate an unknown value.

This simple extension method can help handle such situations:

```
public static class DbDateHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces any date before 01.01.1753 with a Nullable of 
    /// DateTime with a value of null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date">Date to check</param>
    /// <returns>Input date if valid in the DB, or Null if date is 
    /// too early to be DB compatible.</returns>
    public static DateTime? ToNullIfTooEarlyForDb(this DateTime date)
    {
        return (date >= (DateTime) SqlDateTime.MinValue) ? date : (DateTime?)null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 DateTime? dateToPassOnToDb = tooEarlyDate.ToNullIfTooEarlyForDb();
```

Answer (score 24):

Simple.
On your code first, set the type of DateTime to DateTime?.
So you can work with nullable DateTime type in database.
Entity example:

```
public class Alarme
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DataDisparado { get; set; }//.This allow you to work with nullable datetime in database.
        public DateTime? DataResolvido { get; set; }//.This allow you to work with nullable datetime in database.
        public long Latencia { get; set; }

        public bool Resolvido { get; set; }

        public int SensorId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SensorId")]
        public virtual Sensor Sensor { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: that's not always the case.   
{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}   

also makes this error emerge

Answer (score 14):

Even though this question is quite old and there are great answers already, I thought I should put one more which explains 3 different approaches to solve this problem.

**1st Approach**

Explicitly map `DateTime` property `public virtual DateTime Start { get; set; }` to `datetime2` in corresponding column in the table. Because by default EF will map it to `datetime`.

This can be done by fluent API or data annotation.

1. Fluent API

   In DbContext class overide `OnModelCreating` and configure property `Start` (for  explanation reasons it's a property of EntityClass class).

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       //Configure only one property 
       modelBuilder.Entity<EntityClass>()
           .Property(e => e.Start)
           .HasColumnType("datetime2");

      //or configure all DateTime Preperties globally(EF 6 and Above)
       modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
           .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
   }
   ```
2. Data annotation

   ```
   [Column(TypeName="datetime2")]
   public virtual DateTime Start { get; set; }
   ```

**2nd Approach**

Initialize `Start` to a default value in EntityClass constructor.This is good as if for some reason the value of `Start` is not set before saving the entity into the database start will always have a default value. Make sure default value is greater than or equal to [SqlDateTime.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) ( from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999)

```
public class EntityClass
{
    public EntityClass()
    {
        Start= DateTime.Now;
    }
    public DateTime Start{ get; set; }
}
```

**3rd Approach**

Make `Start` to be of type nullable `DateTime` **-note** `?` after `DateTime`-

```
public virtual DateTime? Start { get; set; }
```

For more explanation read this [post](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/229/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of)

Answer (score 13):

You can make the field nullable, if that suits your specific modeling concerns.  A null date won't be coerced to a date that isn't within the range of the SQL DateTime type the way a default value would.  Another option is to explicitly map to a different type, perhaps with,

```
.HasColumnType("datetime2")
```

Answer (score 8):

If your `DateTime` properties are nullable in the database then be sure to use `DateTime?` for the associated object properties or EF will pass in `DateTime.MinValue` for unassigned values which is outside of the range of what the SQL datetime type can handle.

Answer (score 8):

My solution was to switch all datetime columns to datetime2, and use datetime2 for any new columns. In other words make EF use datetime2 by default. Add this to the OnModelCreating method on your context:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```

That will get all the DateTime and DateTime? properties on all your entities.

Answer (score 3):

initialize the Start property in the constructor

```
Start = DateTime.Now;
```

This worked for me when I was trying to add few new fields to the ASP .Net Identity Framework's Users table (AspNetUsers) using Code First.
I updated the Class - ApplicationUser in IdentityModels.cs and I added a field lastLogin of type DateTime.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            LastPassUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String MiddleName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String EmailId { get; set; }
        public String ContactNo { get; set; }
        public String HintQuestion { get; set; }
        public String HintAnswer { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsUserActive { get; set; }

        //Auditing Fields
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastPassUpdate { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on user @andygjp's answer, its better if you override the base `Db.SaveChanges()` method and add a function to override any date which does not fall between SqlDateTime.MinValue and SqlDateTime.MaxValue.

Here is the sample code

```
public class MyDb : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        UpdateDates();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void UpdateDates()
    {
        foreach (var change in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified)))
        {
            var values = change.CurrentValues;
            foreach (var name in values.PropertyNames)
            {
                var value = values[name];
                if (value is DateTime)
                {
                    var date = (DateTime)value;
                    if (date < SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
                    {
                        values[name] = SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
                    }
                    else if (date > SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value)
                    {
                        values[name] = SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from the user @sky-dev's comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11297294/9158120

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and in my case I was setting the date to new DateTime() instead of DateTime.Now

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened when I used entity and the sql table has default value of datetime == getdate().
so what I did to set a value to this field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Database First and when this error happened to me my solution was to force ProviderManifestToken="2005" in edmx file (making the models compatible with SQL Server 2005).
Don't know if something similar is possible for Code First.

Answer (score 0):

One line fixes this:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```

So, in my code, I added:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
}
```

Adding that one line to the DBContext subclass override void OnModelCreating section should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after some refactoring in EF6, my tests were failing with the same error message as the original poster but my solution had nothing to do with the DateTime fields.

I was just missing a required field when creating the entity. Once I added the missing field, the error went away. My entity does have two DateTime? fields but they weren't the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone is as dopey as me, double check the year of your date.  I was converting a date from a text file in YYMMDD format so was creating a date with a year of 0020, not 2020.  Obvious error but I spent more time looking at it but not seeing it than I should have!