# conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type error with EF Code first?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using EF Code first with my asp.net mvc application.
here is my code:

```
Request.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
```

the type of RequestDate is datetime in my database.
and this is error that occurred when i use the above code!:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

please help me. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/c-sharp-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type)

Comment: Are you using SQL 2005 ? datetime2 range is from 0001 / 01 / 01 through  to 9999 / 12 / 31 hence the error. If so, you'll need to edit the XML edmx file

Comment: @json jong: I'm using sql server 2008 and i have no .edmx file because i use Code first!.

Comment: Can't be answered without seeing the class model and the (full) code throwing the exception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit:

[How to fix the datetime2 out-of-range conversion error using DbContext and SetInitializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050906/how-to-fix-the-datetime2-out-of-range-conversion-error-using-dbcontext-and-setin)

The issue is that you are trying to save a value that cannot fit in a SQL datetime column. the answer givin here will stop the conversion from failing.

or in your Database change the columns to be type datetime2. I don't exactly know why they code first is generating datetime columns instead of datetime2

Here is an example to explicitly map your Datetime columns to datetime2 in SQL

[Using DateTime properties in Code-First Entity Framework and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043816/using-datetime-properties-in-code-first-entity-framework-and-sql-server/8044310#8044310)

Comment: I'm using Code First and i have no .edmx file.

Comment: I Think what you need to do is specify the column is of type datetime. Did your code first generate the Database?
your trying to store a datetime2 object in a datetime column

Comment: Yes my database generated successfully with code first and that column is of type datetime.

Comment: What SQL database are you using?

Answer (score 9):

On my side it was because the datetime was not nullable and in some situation the field was not initialized in the constructor.
I solved this by setting my field as nullable

```
public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

Another solution would be to initialize the field in the constructor no matter what.

Comment: This solved it for me. On reflection the error message isn't great. I created a DateTime column, why is it trying to convert it to something else? why not just tell me a constraint has been violated...

Answer (score 0):

```
    --in your sql script:
        create table tablename(mydate DateTime not null default GETDATE())


        //in your c# object:
        public class tablename
        {
          public string mydate {get; set; } = null;
        }

        //in your C# method using EF:
        private async Task mymethod()
        {
            DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            dbContext.tablename.add(new tablenam{mydate = sqlFormattedDate });
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```