# Code First: why would getdate() be out of range?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a column as follows:

```
[Column(TypeName="smalldatetime")]
public DateTime LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
```

In the `Seed` method I have:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Alter Table Members Add Default getdate() for LastUpdatedOn");
```

and also inserted some sample rows.

The database is created fine, including the default values, but when the sample rows are inserted I get:

> "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a smalldatetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."

Why would the current time be out of range for `smalldatetime`?  I want to stick to `smalldatetime` for the database.  How do I do it?

PS: When the database column is the default `datetime` type, I also get the same error.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050906/how-to-fix-the-datetime2-out-of-range-conversion-error-using-dbcontext-and-setin. LastUpdatedOn will be `DateTime.MinValue` by default. Either use a `DateTime?` where empty values will be saved as `NULL`, or set a within-range value in the constructor.

Comment: I see. So EF does not leave the column as null but populates it with DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: The default value in C# for DateTime is `DateTime.MinValue`. EF just saves that value.