# The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value exception

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert only Date and Card into my database table and I'm getting the below error

> Error Exception {"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Here is my table structure

[image]

Here is my class for TimeOutJustification

```
    public class TimeoutJustification
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Card { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOut { get; set; }
        public long TotalTime { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public TimeSpan TotalTimeSpan
        {
            get
            {
                return new TimeSpan(TotalTime);
            }
            set
            {
                TotalTime = value.Ticks;
            }
        }
        public string Justification { get; set; }

        public string Details { get; set; }

        public string GeneralJustification { get; set; } 

    }
}
```

An error exception The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated." get caught whenever I'm saving into database.

Hence I'm using entity framework and my ID in my database is auto increment

Here is an example of how it looks like

```
List<TimeoutJustification>withOutTimeOuts;

withOutTimeOuts.Add(new TimeOutJustification{Card="1234",Date="12-03-19"}

db.JustificationTable.AddRange(withOutTimeOuts);
//Error Gets Caught here
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Please post the `TimeOutJustification` class. It's not clear if the DateTime properties are nullable or not.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/6050906/861716.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime2` coveres a larger range than `datetime`.

**datetime2**:

Date range  0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31

**datetime**:

Date range  January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

`Date="12-03-19"` probably converts to year 12 (or 19). The solution could be using `DateTime` for the `Date` property:

```
public class TimeOutJustification
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm already using DateTime for my Date property

Comment: That's not the issue. It's in the other date properties.