# ObjectContext.SaveChanges() never returns if new object added to an ObjectSet. Has anyone experienced this?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, sql-server-express

I have an EF4 EDM called `UnitHistoryEntities`. The database is stored in SQL Express 2012. Windows 7 64-bit.

1. I create a new context with `context = new UnitHistoryEntities()`.
2. I pass this context into a couple dialog boxes that collect a bit of information from the user. A few queries were probably performed during this.
3. Based on that input, I construct a new Unit entity with `var unit = new Unit()`, set a few properties, and add it to the context with `context.Units.AddObject(unit)`
4. I then call `context.SaveChanges()`.

The call to `SaveChanges()` never, ever returns (I've given it at least 10 minutes) and never throws an exception. If I remove the `AddObject()`, it returns without making any changes to the database, because nothing was modified.

Why does `SaveChanges()` never return? Anyone experience this phenomenon?

I am able to connect and perform queries on the database from SQL Management Studio while my program is in this condition.

Comment: `Never, ever`? How do you know?  How long have you given it?

Comment: At least 10 minutes. Should be plenty of time for something to happen. My database is pretty much empty at the moment. Queries are happening, so I know connectivity is good. The next statement is `MessageBox.Show()`, and I've set a breakpoint there that never gets hit. A step over (or step in) never does anything.

Comment: I don't suppose the database is locked up? Are you able to query the DB while your program is hung?

Comment: Good idea. Yes, I just tried it. I'm able to connect with SQL Server Management Studio and query the tables involved. SQL Express 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem I'm having is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608734/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-o). I have a DateTime field that I was not setting. I made a console app that performed exactly the same actions on the context that my application was doing. In this case, `SaveChanges()` **did** return, with the exception `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.`

So I now set my DateTime field to 1/1/1900 and I'll treat that like a null date. My program now operates properly.

Strange that I didn't get an exception thrown in my WPF application, but I did in the console application...

Answer (score 0):

the entity its function is to add to the table,each table has a function called himself
,you can add following to the database with Entity:

```
UnitHistoryEntities context=new UnitHistoryEntities();
Unit unit=new Unit();
unit.field1=value1;
unit.field2=value2;
context.AddtoUnit(unit);
context.SaveChange();
```

Comment: Tried that. No change. I'm going to distill down to bare minimum code that causes this and post an update with code and model.

Answer (score 0):

This is because EF threw DbEntityValidationException on the data you are trying to insert. If EF suppress the error, you can log the the query and error using.

```
context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```