# Getting MAX value in column: The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am using SQLite in my application and my table is defined as per this EF model:

```
internal class Board
{
    public string BoardID { get; set; }
    public ushort BoardNumber { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Board()
    {
        BoardID = string.Empty;
        Content = string.Empty;
        BoardNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

The property names match exactly the database columns. I am able to fetch records with the same model using LINQ to Entity. However, when I try this operation it fails with the error stated in the subject:

```
using (var db = new Models.EF.MyDbContext())
{
     int last - db.Boards.Max(n => n.BoardNumber);
}
```

The column in the database is named "BoardNumber" and is of type integer (SQLite) and is NOT the PK.

Why is this operation failing?

Comment: See what query is generated using the profiler and then try executing the same query against the sqllite db directly and see if it works.

Comment: Don't yo have a typo there? the negative sign should be replaced with an assignment (=) sign, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because your current type is a `ushort` and [unsigned integers and types are not supported in LINQ to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317(v=vs.110).aspx#UnsignedIntsUnsupported).

You may want to consider using a different type if that is feasible, or consider implementing another approach for reading those specific values [similar to the one mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26436056/557445).