# Specified cast is not valid when querying MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Connecting to MySQL database via MySQL.Data.Entity v6.9.9 (the current version). Trying to retrieve the list of all 
tables via a straight SQL query (within `MyDBContext`):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DBTableInfo>> GetTablesAsync()
{
    string sql = @"SELECT TABLE_NAME Name, TABLE_ROWS NumRows 
        FROM information_schema.tables
        where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
        order by TABLE_NAME;";
    var result = Database.SqlQuery<DBTableInfo>(sql);
    return await result.ToListAsync();
}
```

`DBTableInfo` is defined simply as:

```
public class DBTableInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long NumRows { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

The offending line is the `return` statement of the `GetTableAsync` method. The error occurs because of 
the `NumRows` property of `DBTableInfo`. If I comment out `NumRows` property from `DBTableInfo`, the query works.

Now, the `information_schema.tables` defines `TABLE_ROWS` as `bigint`. My `DBTableInfo` object 
declares the corresponding property as `long`. Even though this column does not contain nulls, I also tried with `long?`, 
and it does not work either.

Why? Any suggestions on the best way to deal with it will be appreciated.

Comment: If you change the NumRows property to object instead of long, you can check which type is actually being used to deserialize the TABLE_ROWS value. Have you tried checking that?

Comment: @Mt. Schneiders It comes back as null.

Comment: Have you tried using decimal as the datatype?

Comment: @Mt. Schneiders Actually, it seems to come back as `System.UInt64`, a.k.a. `ulong`. But I am getting zero as the value for all tables, even those that are not empty. And no, `decimal` doesn't work either.

Comment: Assuming the query is correct, you could try casting the column value on the SQL query itself.

Comment: Casting to what? It needs to be an integer for my purposes. The query runs fine in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: You could try casting the BIGINT column to INT. Don't know if that would actually change the way MySQL deserializes the value.

Comment: @Mt. Schneiders You were right. I was reluctant to do this, because of the possible overflow, but in the end, that turns out the only way to do it, and the overflow won't happen before I retire. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved (more like "worked around") by casting the `NumRows` value to a signed version in SQL like this:

```
CAST(TABLE_ROWS as SIGNED) NumRows
```

**and** ensuring my class is still defined as:

```
public class DBTableInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long NumRows { get; set; } // <-- ulong does not work!
}
```

With those two steps, the records deserialize correctly.

Note that you cannot use `ulong` (unsigned 64-bit integer) as the declared type for `NumRows` because - as it turns out - **unsigned longs are still not supported by Entity Framework**. It took me a while to re-learn this.

Here is a relevant reference:

[How to use unsigned int / long types with Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303631/how-to-use-unsigned-int-long-types-with-entity-framework)

So, you have to **both** cast the unsigned long value from the database to a signed version, **and** declare the receiving member of the class as (signed) `long`.

Unfortunately, this leaves the room open for overflow errors on MySQL side. Fortunately, my tables are nowhere near the number of rows where that would become a real problem.