# Code First approach using uint as primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, uint

I was making a code first approach in MVC to generate tables. I am trying to make my Employee class's primary key to be uint to prevent negative values but apparently, I always get an exception. Is there a decorate code for an int type to prevent negative or a workaround to allow uint as primary key?

```
public class Employee
{
     [Key]
     [Column(Order = 0)]
     public uint EmployeeId { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Your questuon has _nothing_ to do with MVC or Web.

Comment: `uint` should be possible but it is not advised. Just use `int`.

Comment: if you want higher precision than `int` then use `long` instead of `uint`.

Comment: Unsigned integers are unsupported in many SQL databases. For example, SQL server will just use `long` to "support" `uint`. Use `int` and ensure that it is not negative in your domain code. Also, consider using just `Id`. It is in `Employee` class, so it already implies that `Id` is employee ID.

Comment: the unsigned integers/signed bytes are only really in the C# language to support interop scenarios. They should never be your preference if you're picking a type *from scratch*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26436056/10561636).

Besides that, uint is not [CLS compliant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.85)), so it's generally not recommended to use