# The conversion of a datetime 2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Cant understand the reason for this bug.

**The conversion of a datetime 2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

The data type in Sql server for this column is DateTime and Not Null is selected while creating the column.

On debugging systems datetime is saved in the column exception occurs in SaveChanges.

On searching I got this

[Stack Over Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608734/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-o)

[The Conversion..](http://Stack%20Over%20Flow)
But didn't helped in my situation.

Model

```
public class Student
{  
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

Action

```
public ActionResult Save(ViewModels.Student student)
{
        var model = new ViewModels.Student();
        model.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        db.Student.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Your saving `student`, not `model` and presumably `student.CreatedDate` is the default `DateTime.MinDate` (which is out of range)

Comment: @Stephen i tried student.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now then too the same error,some thing I am missing.

Comment: That should work fine if your setting it before you save `student` (assuming there are no other `DateTime` fields)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke it worked.

Answer (score 2):

SqlDateTime.MinValue is January 1, 1753 while DateTime.MinValue is January 1, 0001

You need to handle this and make sure it is higher than the minimum value when you do the save